# Import Excel Spreadsheet to MySQL DB using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel, import

I've got this problem of importing excel data to MySQL database. I want to create a VB.net application that allows the user to browse the excel file then click upload and automatically all the data in the excel file will be saved into the database.

I've already created a VB.net form with the browse thing and my only problem is the saving of the data. Can someone help me please.. thanks..

Comment: Are you expecting the Excel data to simply be stored as a BLOB or CLOB in the database?  Or else, how do you expect a selected spreadsheet to map onto the table structure within your database?

Answer (score 1):

1. Store Excel file as comma separated text - CSV file.
2. Import data using [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Comment: thanks Devart for your answer...  For the days that past, I've made to  display the data to gridview in vb.net.  and next to it is to save it to database... http://blueraiden.exofire.net/blog/import-excel-spreadsheet-data-to-datagridview-using-vb-net

Comment: http://blueraiden.exofire.net/blog/import-excel-spreadsheet-data-to-datagridview-using-vb-net